# it's relative or absolute path?

Tags: linux, path

```
ex    mkdir -p mytree/{dir1/{dir4,dir5/dir6},dir3,dir2}
```

I'm trying to do absolute path without using cd command but I want to sure if it's relative or abs path?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The path you specified is a relative path. When you want to have the absolute path you need to specify the path from root directory (**/**).

```
mkdir -p mytree/{dir1/{dir4,dir5/dir6},dir3,dir2}
```

creates a new directory from present working directory (pwd),

while

```
 mkdir -p /mytree/{dir1/{dir4,dir5/dir6},dir3,dir2}
```

creates a new directory from root directory

Comment: if i'm just put the root(/) before mytree dir it will be abs path ?? like what you did before( mkdir -p /mytree/{dir1/{dir4,dir5/dir6},dir3,dir2})

Comment: Not directly. Only if you want to create **mytree** inside root (at **/mytree**). When you want to create the directory at let's say **/home/user/xyz** then you have to type **mkdir -p /home/user/xyz/mytree/...**. Always specify the path before the **pwd**.

Comment: so for example, if I want to do subdirectory under my home dir lets called it pro1 then the command should be like this mkdir pro1 then cd pro1 then  mkdir -p /pro1/mytree/{dir1/{dir4,dir5/dir6},dir3,dir2} ? Does it make sense?

Comment: No, you will then create a directory with path **/pro1/mytree**, so that directory wouldn't be in your home diretory. You can see your current path from root with the command **pwd**. Just type it in and you will see your current directory you're in.  The mkdir command is then like **mkdir -p <pwd output>/mytree/...** when you are currently in **/home/user/pro1**

Answer (score -1):

It looks like relative path, because absolute path should starts from `/`.

For example:

If you are in `/home/user` directory and execute `mkdir -p example/some_dir` then command will create folders in `/home/user` and absolute way your new dirs looks like `/home/user/example/some_dir`.